# Is PARTITION RANGE ALL in your explain plan bad?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, sql-execution-plan

Here's my explain plan:

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS   244492 4525870 235345240
 SORT ORDER BY   244492 4525870 235345240
  **PARTITION RANGE ALL**   207633 4525870 235345240
   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN MCT MCT_PLANNED_CT_PK 207633 4525870 235345240
```

Just wondering if this is the best optimized plan for querying huge partitioned tables.

*Using Oracle10g*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PARTITION RANGE ALL` just means that the predicates could not be used to perform any partition pruning. [More info.](http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/partition%20prune.html) Or, that the alternative (scanning the table blocks instead of using a fast full scan on the index) was estimated to be more expensive overall.

If you can change the predicate to limit the affected rows to a small subset of the partitions, the database will be able to skip whole partitions when querying the table.